# Product import successfully done no errors but no products imported in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7, magento-2.2.5, product-import

I have manually added 400 products in Magento 2.1.7 CE via the backend. There are configurable products involved, their associated simple products, and normal simple products (not associated with configurable products).

I am exporting all products via System->Export and start examining the csv file.
First thing is that in configurable_variations column, not all attributes used for skus associated with each configurable product are in the exported file. 
I add those manually. i.e. only color was listed for some products-skus with color and size: I added size as well and vise versa.

Second I need to add these products into 2 different store views (languages -el - en) already created in the backend. Categories, attribute sets etc. are already created too. All exported fields are involved in the import.
Simple products come first in the file, second are simple products associated with configurable and configurable products are last for both store views (800 entries).

I am trying to update products (Add/Update mode), no luck. I manually delete all products and try to import: "Import successfully done", but no products imported. No errors, no logs. I've tried to completely remove description and short description fields, in case improper characters are involved, no luck.

I am convinced I miss something and it's me learning. But is it a typo? how to identify what is wrong in this csv file which is large - not just 2 test products? I have gone through this carefully: https://goo.gl/erH7aQ and have made many updates. I am not sure what is wrong anymore.

**Update**

Thanks Rajkumar .E. ..basic knowledge: Started with one simple product then a few more, etc and found some problems mainly in Categories. Importing Configurable products is not the most straight forward thing at first, but import works. Last import attempt was still giving "errors" (maybe on something not very important) but also "import successfully done" and data imported. I set "Stop on Error" and Allowed Errors Count to 410

**Update**

In my case, there was 49 products only and Import was successfully done but, no products were added even after clearing cache and doing re-index. I have recently updated our magento version to 2.2.5 (Community Edition).

I have also tried with removing special character from the CSV but still no success. Let me know if I have to re-post this issue or is there any solution for this.

[image]

Comment: after `Import successfully done`  can you check `admin->products->catalog` any product are there

Comment: I checked multiple times. I have reindexed. No products in admin->products->catalog.

Comment: create one csv file with one simple product, Then  import, after check it. and  also use  `Import Behavior` as a `Stop on Error `

Comment: hi have you find any solution to this.Plz help me I am facing same problem

Comment: did you reindex the site? I also have same issue, if I enter 1000 product only show 10 etc. I saw some time its a reindexe issue, but it didnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Found out some product names contained curved apostrophes instead of straight ones. It was saying successful but no products were added even after trying 4 times. I had these (’) instead of ('). Did a mass replace and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

if your issue still persists:

Try uploading your csv data into a Google Spreadsheet file on Google Drive and then download csv and import it. Sometimes, the regular .csv (MS-Excel or something) might have special characters or garbage characters in it and this might prevent products data from being properly imported.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

i have uploaded the csv data into a Google Spreadsheet file on Google Drive and then downloaded csv and imported successfully magento products.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a lead from @Jean-Sebastien's answer:

I used an online tool https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/ to detect and **remove all non-ascii characters** from my product description column and then the upload was successful.

Answer (score 0):

As Moin Shaikh and Rashid said previously. You can upload your csv file to google drive and then download it as csv. It can help you remove all unecessary characters from your csv file.

You can verify that your products are imported properly by logging into your magento backend and going to **System >> Data Transfer >> Import History**.

On the last column of **Import History** page you will find the count of all products that has been imported or updated. Optionally, you can also download your uploaded csv file for troubleshooting.